# where is my Stack Exchange inbox

Tags: support

I want to delete my account on superuser.com. I received a mail from `do-not-reply@stackexchange.com` saying:

...
We recently received your request to delete your Super User profile.
A self-deletion link has been made available in your Stack Exchange inbox. Just sign in, click the link, and your profile will be removed in 24 hours

But, I cannot find my Stack Exchange inbox. Could someone give me a link ?

Answer (score 2):

It's the one next to the Stack Exchange logo.

[image]

Comment: but, there is no any link to delete my account ?

Comment: @bonaca check for items in inbox? Should be there. else please do [edit] and post a screenshot of your inbox

Comment: I found  and clicked the link and got - `Page Not Found`...